# Toggle-able USB hub with more than one input and output?

Tags: usb, productivity, hub, splitter

I recently came across this product:
http://ppa-usa.com/shared-network-hub-4-port-usb.html

The only problem is, this is nearly opposite of what I need.

Ideally, I'm looking for a USB hub-like device that can accept at least two devices for input, and toggle those two devices between at least 2 PC's. The hub linked above appears to be only able to accept one device.

Does anyone know of such a product?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a USB KVM switch with a USB hub connected to it.

```
                                                         +----------+
    +------+                                        +--->| Device A |
    |      |                                        |    +----------+
    | PC 1 |+-----+                                 |
    |      |      |    +---------+     +----------+ |    +----------+
    +------+      +--->|         |     |          |++  +>| Device B |
                       | KVM     |+--->| USB Hub  |+---+ +----------+
    +------+      +--->|         |     |          |++
    |      |      |    +---------+     +----------+ |    +----------+
    | PC 2 |+-----+                                 +--->| Device C |
    |      |                                             +----------+
    +------+
```

A KVM switch has a switch (hardware or keyboard-controlled versions available) so that the USB hub (along with the devices connected to it ) ends up being connected to either PC 1 or PC 2.